# JavaScript - compare multiple arrays to one

Tags: javascript, arrays, comparison

I would like to output which of 'buns' and 'duns' has the most elements in common with 'me'. How should I do this?

```
var buns = ['bap', 'bun', 'bop'];
var duns = ['dap', 'dun', 'dop'];

var me = ['dap', 'bun', 'bop'];
```

Comment: Is the index important?

Comment: Index is not important and this is just a simplification of an algorithm for an application I am creating

Comment: Post what you have tried, or any ideas you have - it's important to make an attempt

Comment: Compute the intersection of each array with the target array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reduce` over the array to be tested and check if each element is in `me`.

```
function common(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr2.reduce(function (p, c) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(c) > -1) p++;
    return p;
  }, 0);
}

common(me, buns); // 2
common(me, duns); // 1
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4y3pnuyr/)

Answer (score 0):

Index important

```
function hamd(a, b) {
    return a.reduce((sum, item, i) => {
        if (item !== b[i]) return sum + 1;
        return sum;
    }, 0);
}
```

Index not important, duplicates not important

```
function diff(a, b) {
    return a.reduce((sum, item, i) => {
        if (b.indexOf(item) === -1) return sum + 1;
        return sum;
    }, 0);
}
```

Index not important, duplicates important

```
function diffU(a, b) {
    b = b.slice();
    return a.reduce((sum, item, i) => {
        let i = b.indexOf(item);
        if (i === -1) return sum + 1;
        b.splice(i, 1);
        return sum;
    }, 0);
}
```

The one with the lowest score has the most similarity, e.g.

```
diff(me, buns) // 1
diff(me, duns) // 2
// `buns` is more like `me` than `duns`
```

---

Please note that these are not commutative operations when the length of the *Array* is not the same; `diff(a, b)` may be different to `diff(b, a)` when `a.length !== b.length`
If you want to compare the results you need the common array on the same side of all tests